# How to check any every array object property empty or not?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash, is-empty

The purpose of function is to get **false** when all `answers` are empty. Currently, some how getting **false when only one single `answers` empty and rest have data inside.

what is the best way to check all `answers` are empty or not. It doesn't matter some has data and some doesn't. I just wanna see all empty or not.

```js
const questions = [{
    "answers": [{
        "value": "Browns",
        "selected": false,
      },
      {
        "value": "Oranges",
        "selected": false,
      },
      {
        "value": "Purples",
        "selected": false,
      }
    ],
    "info": "",
    "type": "DESELECT",
    "lastUpdated": "2021-11-01T22:50:28.359"
  },
  {
    "answers": [],
    "info": "",
    "type": "DESELECT",
    "lastUpdated": "2021-11-01T22:50:35.392"
  },
  {
    "answers": [{
        "value": "AnimalPrints",
        "selected": false,
      },
      {
        "value": "BigLogos",
        "selected": true,
      },
      {
        "value": "Floral",
        "selected": false,
      }
    ],
    "info": "",
    "type": "DESELECT",
    "lastUpdated": "2021-11-01T22:50:43.883"
  }
];

console.clear();
console.log("------------ES6------------");
const es6Result = questions.every((item) => !_.isEmpty(item.answers));
console.log(es6Result);

const lodashResult = _.every(questions, !_.isEmpty('answers'));
console.log("------------Lodash------------");
console.log(lodashResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.some()`, you will get `true` if at least 1 `answers` is not empty, and you will get `false` if all `answers` are empty

```
const es6Result = questions.some((item) => item.answers.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic you describe requires:

```
const lodashResult = !_.every(questions, _.isEmpty('answers'));
```

or

```
const es6Result = !questions.every((item) => _.isEmpty(item.answers));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const questions = [{
    "answers": [{
        "value": "Browns",
        "selected": false,
      },
      {
        "value": "Oranges",
        "selected": false,
      },
      {
        "value": "Purples",
        "selected": false,
      }
    ],
    "info": "",
    "type": "DESELECT",
    "lastUpdated": "2021-11-01T22:50:28.359"
  },
  {
    "answers": [],
    "info": "",
    "type": "DESELECT",
    "lastUpdated": "2021-11-01T22:50:35.392"
  },
  {
    "answers": [{
        "value": "AnimalPrints",
        "selected": false,
      },
      {
        "value": "BigLogos",
        "selected": true,
      },
      {
        "value": "Floral",
        "selected": false,
      }
    ],
    "info": "",
    "type": "DESELECT",
    "lastUpdated": "2021-11-01T22:50:43.883"
  }
];

console.clear();
console.log("------------ES6------------");
const es6Result = questions.map((item) => _.isEmpty(item.answers)).indexOf(true) > -1;
console.log(es6Result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's not really a need for lodash here. You should be able to accomplish what you want by using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?retiredLocale=it)

```
questions.every((item) => item.answers.length > 0)
```

This will always return true, as long as all 'answers' array have one or more items inside, else false.
As [Georgy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69884809/6802127) said, you can use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) when you want to check for at least one of the items.